# Anonymous function not executing

Tags: javascript, lambda, lodash

I'm fairly new to javascript/lodash and assume this is something simple but I haven't been able to figure it out.  I am trying to use the `_.get` method to pick a value out of an object and default to an anonymous function where I carry out some logic to return a value.  However, the function is not executing.  Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
var object = { 'cat': 'meow', 'dog': 'bark' } 
 
_.get(object, 'sheep', ()=>{ return 'blah blah blah'} );
// => ''
```

If I replace the lambda function with just the string, it works fine.  How can I get the function to execute?

Comment: Quick tip: With arrow functions that are only a single line, both the `{}` and `return` are implicit. So, `(x, y) => { return x * y; }` is the same as `(x, y) => x * y`. In your case, `() => 'blah blah blah'`.

Comment: If you want to *execute* the value you got as a function, then just add `()` at the end of your expression: `_.get(object, 'sheep', ()=>{ return 'blah blah blah'} )(); //<---`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Using `_.result()` will execute the lambda function as a default.